# How to call two methods @click on a button but execute one method after the other

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to be able to call two different methods on a single button click, but I want the methods to run one after the other.
Indeed, I have my first method which creates multiple instances of a component and the second one is going to move these instances on my screen.
I didn't find a solution to create the instances and move them in a single method so I want to do it that way.

I tried by calling the two methods like this : `@click="method1(); method2();"` but the two methods are executed at the same time.

So these are the methods I am dealing with:

```
 modifyLayer(){
    console.log(this.selectedLayer)
    this.modifyingLayer = this.selectedLayer
    var donnéesCouche = this.couche.find(element => element.id == this.modifyingLayer)
    this.emplacement=[]
    this.emplacement = donnéesCouche.listePositions
    
  },

  moveLayer(){
    for (var element in this.emplacement){
      var toMove=document.getElementById(this.emplacement[element].id)
      for (var element in this.emplacement){
        toMove.top=this.emplacement[element].x
        toMove.left=this.emplacement[element].y
      }
    }
  },
```

`this.emplacement` corresponds to a list of objects like this: `{id: ....; x: "...px"; y: "...px"}` and in my HTML, I create instances of my component with a `v-for` each element in `this.emplacement`

Could you help me find a solution, either to call the two methods one after the other or to be able to create instances and move them within the same method?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to call two different methods on a single button click, but I want the methods to run one after the other

Well, the handler as `@click="method1(); method2();"` indeed runs the methods one after another (1st returns before 2nd starts)

> I have my first method which creates multiple instances of a component and the second one is going to move these instances on my screen.

This is little bit unfortunate wording. Your fist method does not create any components directly. It just assigns some data into `emplacement` data member and this `emplacement` property is used in the template to render some components...

So your problem is not that those methods are not executed one after another (they are), problem is that Vue is using [async update queue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue) to update the DOM

So when the `modifyLayer()` finishes executing, DOM elements for the `emplacement` does not exist yet. The solution is to postpone the `moveLayer()` execution using the [$nextTick()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick) method

So instead of `@click="method1(); method2();"` handler, create a method:

`@click="handleClick"`

```js
methods: {
  handleClick() {
   this.modifyLayer()
   this.$nextTick(this.moveLayer)
  }
}
```

Note: even tho I do not understand why you rendering 1st and moving later instead of rendering everything in one go at correct possition. Something like `document.getElementById` is not needed in Vue in most cases....

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the second method from the first one, and call the first method on button click. `@click="modifyLayer()"`

```
 modifyLayer(){
    console.log(this.selectedLayer)
    this.modifyingLayer = this.selectedLayer
    var donnéesCouche = this.couche.find(element => element.id == this.modifyingLayer)
    this.emplacement=[]
    this.emplacement = donnéesCouche.listePositions
    this.moveLayer();   // calling the second method from the first
  },

  moveLayer(){
    for (var element in this.emplacement){
      var toMove=document.getElementById(this.emplacement[element].id)
      for (var element in this.emplacement){
        toMove.top=this.emplacement[element].x
        toMove.left=this.emplacement[element].y
      }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this and it says that I can't set property of null because the document is not updated while a method is running so it won't work like this because the second method is called in the first one: there is no pause between the two when the document could update its content

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do something like that : `@click="methods()"`

And then declare :

```
async methods{
await this.methods1()
this.methods2()
}
```